# Any way to change the clipping rect of the current context in UIView.drawRect?

Tags: uiview, drawrect, cgcontext

I have a custom class which overrides the `point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool` function so that small buttons can have a touchable area greater than their frame. I thought it would be convenient if I could draw this touchable area around the button when working in Interface Builder. I overrode drawRect to fill the touchable area, but it seems that drawRect clips to the view's frame. Is there any way to change the clipping area to something bigger? I'd rather not add a child view for something like this.

Comment: Hi, have you fix your problem? It would be great if you share it. Thanks.

Comment: @Evana It does not seem to be possible.

Comment: Yes I found it so. Thanks.